# Custom Information Message for user based on another cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, spreadsheet

I am busy with an optimization spreadsheet which needs to display an information message, maybe similar to the Input Message for data validation (but I am open to suggestions). This message will be used to display typical minimum, maximum and a recommended user defined value based on another cell value. The user may then choose a value from this informative message and use that in the calculations going forward, but if the user determines that the value chosen is no longer appropriate, then the user needs to go back and see the same min, max and avg. values as a guideline to choose from.

Below is an over-simplified version of what I want to achieve. The text that needs to be displayed in this informative message will be part a data table.

[image]

My *limitation* is that I can not display this message in additional rows/columns cells as this spreadsheet is a company standard spreadsheet and many other sheets reference these specific cells.

The *problem* that I would like to solve is eliminate user error. Normally the user will select an item from a drop down list (using data validation) and the user needs to refer to text books as to what value should be used for this item in the remainder of the calculations - this creates inconsistancy and sometime user error.

Comment: You may want to look into Cascading Drop Down lists

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that meets my needs - this is not completed yet as I need to add the lookup text to a cell or text box.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Const WS_RANGE As String = "F64:L73"
Dim InfoText As String
Dim TypeLookup As String
Dim LookupTable As Range

Dim TXTHELP As String

    On Error GoTo ws_exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(WS_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then
        With Target

            TypeLookup = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value
            DNLookup = Cells(45, ActiveCell.Column)
               
            With Worksheets("Data_MinorLoss")
                Set LookupTable = .Range("A3:O8")
                
            End With
            
            InfoText = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TypeLookup, LookupTable, 2, False)
            
                       
            'MsgBox InfoText
            
        End With
    End If

ws_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```